# RTL8821AE wifi is getting disconnected automatically after a few seconds

Tags: wireless, realtek-wireless

I have RTL8821AE wifi in my laptop and it is getting disconnected automatically after a few seconds i tried updating my system also I tried this command also

sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms

The problem is still there. Could anybody help with this